# how to wait for the execution of a function

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have this repository , it should get the message by id :

```
  findOne(id: number) {
    return readFile('messages.json', 'utf8', (err, file: string) => {
      const messages = JSON.parse(file);
      return messages[id];
    });
  }
```

this is the service :

```
  findOne(id: number) {
    return this.messagesRepo.findOne(id);
  }
```

and this is the controller

```
  @Get('/:id')
  getMessage(@Param() param: GetMessageDTO) {
    const message = this.messagesService.findOne(param.id);
    if (message == null) {
      throw new NotFoundException('message not found');
    }
    return message;
  }
```

I want the controller to wait for the execution of the function but I can't use async/await because readFile doesn't return promise , what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Use promises api of fs module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `readFile` from `fs`, you can use the one from [promises API of FS module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api) like so:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises'
// ...
 async findOne(id: number): Promise<any> {
    const jsonFileTxtBuffer = await readFile('messages.json');
    const messages = JSON.parse(jsonFileTxtBuffer);
    return messages[id];
  }
```

Don't forget the `await` on calling `.findOne()`, of course.

---

pretty basic JS and node.js stuff not related with NestJS :)